# Trying to toggle a twitch player on/off using javascript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I'm trying to learn some HTML5 stuff for making my own website from scratch.  One thing I wanted to try was putting twitch chat and player in the web page.  Iwant it to start the page with the player absent and the buttons available to be used to turn the player + chat on or off.  Been trying to wrap my head around this and I can't find the solution I'm looking for.  Would appreciate any tips or hints on how to do it, thanks!

```
<a href=" javascript:player()">Display/Hide Player</a>
<a href=" javascript:chat()">Display/Hide Chat</a>

<script>

var playeron = false;
function player()
{
    if(playeron==false)
    {
        playeron=true;
        document.getElementById("MyPlayer").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
        playeron=false;
        document.getElementById("MyPlayer").style.display="none";
    }
}

var chaton=false;
function chat()
{
    if(chaton==false)
    {
        chaton=true;
        document.getElementById("MyChat").style.display="block";
    }
    else
    {
        chaton=false;
        document.getElementById("MyChat").style.display="none";
    }
}
</script>

<iframe id = "MyPlayer" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?volume=0.32&channel=blackdahlia1147" width="1280" height="720"></iframe>

<iframe id = "MyChat" src="https://www.twitch.tv/blackdahlia1147/chat?popout=" width="300" height="720"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
var playeron=false;
var chaton=false;
function player(){
if(playeron==false){
playeron=true;
document.getElementById("MyPlayer").style.display="block";
}else{
playeron=false;
document.getElementById("MyPlayer").style.display="none";
}
}
//try it yourself for chat
</script>




<a href=" javascript:player()">Display/Hide player</a>
<a href=" javascript:chat()">Display/Hide Chat</a>
<style>
iframe{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hm, this gives me the four buttons for showing or hiding the two components but they don't actually do anything.  I'm unsure of what the if statement for "status == false" is doing as well as how the if statement for "toggle == 'p'" works.  I feel like it could be simplified to a single if/else statement for the player and another for the chat, though I am unsure of how these variables work in this at the present time.

Comment: Ok im not next to a computer, does the browser print any errors?

Comment: No errors I'm using Chrome with a local html text file on my computer. It does display the four buttons you wrote in with turning the player/chat on or off, they just don't do anything when clicked. If possible though, I also prefer a toggle button that would just be player on/off and chat on/off but the way functions work in this stump me i don't understand how anything is passed into the functions

Comment: The code you provided also confused me a but because it uses the variable "p" but never uses the variable "c"

Comment: I rewrite it. One moment

Comment: Thanks, at work for another four hours or so so I may not see it for a while. I appreciate the help

Comment: for the lines getElementById("MyPlayer").style.display="block" or "none" are those actual reserved words?  And should I still be using my <iframe> lines from my initial example?  There's some stuff missing that I'm not sure if it's intentional or if I should still be using something from my original work.  Thanks

Comment: Yeah still use your iframes and add the source to them. I was to lazy to include them

Comment: ok I'm trying to get the player to work first, I edited my original question with what I have.  I have a styles.css file in use as well where I put display:none as well as border:none.

Comment: It didn't, no.  I finally figured out what the issue was, chrome didn't like that I set boolean for playeron instead of var, calling it an "unexpected identifier" but I can't see why that is.  Isn't var just a generic data type while boolean is a specified data type?  I did get it to work though changing it and I'll edit my question in a second to show it for posterity.  Thanks for the help man!

Comment: You cannot create a boolean in js like in other languages. You could do var bol=new Boolean(); but you dont need it.

Answer (score 1):

you missed an opening bracket after `function twitch(toggle)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="javascript:toggle('MyPlayer')">Display/Hide Player</a>
<a href="javascript:toggle('MyChat')">Display/Hide Chat</a>
<iframe id="MyPlayer" src="https://player.twitch.tv/?volume=0.32&channel=blackdahlia1147" width="1280" height="720" style="display: block;"></iframe>
<iframe id="MyChat" src="https://www.twitch.tv/blackdahlia1147/chat?popout=" width="300" height="720" style="display: block;"></iframe>

<script>
  function toggle(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if (elem.style.display != 'none') {
      elem.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      elem.style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
```

This will work for you, with the advantage of flexibility if you want to make more things to hide/display.

Comment: Thanks :) I'll take a look when I get back home!

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code and I found that your trying to use variables with links in a if else loop. Now, what I'm saying is you created an option for a loop to search, which is good if you want to create multiple channels for a user to search.

else
       {
           player = "https://player.twitch.tv/?volume=0.32&channel=blackdahlia1147"
          chat = "https://www.twitch.tv/blackdahlia1147/chat?popout="
       }

what you first need to do is learn to add a "plugin" into your HTML if you want those two channels only. Your "player" and "chat" are links to a website, a "plugin" is what you're looking for. Go to youtube and type "plugin", when you get your "plugin" then write:

```
<iframe src="plugin"></iframe>
```

You really don't need the js at this point.

"Onclick" is what you're also looking for. Go to w3school.com and they have great options of buttons and animation options.

Comment: Does not make sense. Please mark inline code by adding four spaces at start. Use official language, not something like "pluggin"